# How to delete without javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make my application work with DELETE action without javascript.

Evrything work as long as my app/view/layout/application.html.haml file do contain the following :

```
!!! 5
%html

  %head
    %title My application
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'screen', :media => 'screen, print, projection'
    /[if IE]
      // CSS for IE
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    ...
```

If I remove the `= javascript_include_tag 'application'` instruction. I can no more delete any  record.
Rails is instead performing a SHOW action.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates made a nice RailsCasts episode on this issue: [Destroy without JavaScript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript-revised).

He simply suggests to add an extra GET member route which will lead to the same controller action when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

The only two supported methods when writing HTML forms are `post` and `get`. If you want to use the `delete` or `put` method you must use AJAX.

That is the reason why most websites use a plain post request and use a special URL. e.g.

```
POST /some-object/delete/
```

or

```
POST /some-object/?action=delete
```

Not even the latest HTML5 draft allows any other method than `post` or `get`: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-fs-method

Rails provides a [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) for performing `put` and `delete` requests. I find this troubling especially as the code does something completely different when JavaScript is disabled.